# how to convert blade file into html and save into folder

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using laravel lumen for making an API. I need to convert blade file into html and save that file into image.

I tried, but not working.

my controller is:

```
public function viewcards()
{
$html = View::make('template1');
$html = $html->render();
$html = html_entity_decode($html);
return response()->json(['CardSave' => $html, 'message' => 'Success'], 201);
}
```

But in response of postman:

```
{
"CardSave": "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>Template One</title>\r\n        <link href=\"http://localhost/ark_newtech_digbiz/digbizcardapi/public/css/style1.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />\r\n        <link href=\"http://localhost/ark_newtech_digbiz/digbizcardapi/public/css/font-awesome.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />
}
```

why showing **\r\n** and not taking **<** in response.
And how to save it into html?

I am stuck from 2 days. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$html = View::make('template1');
$html = $html->render();
$html = html_entity_decode($html);
File::put('test.html',
    view('resources.views.test')
        ->with(['CardSave' => $html, 'message' => 'Success'])
        ->render()
);
```

Comment: File::put('test.html',
                view('template1')
                    ->with(['CardSave' => $html, 'message' => 'Success'])
                    ->render()
            );

Comment: what happen @Vinod

Comment: undefined variable html

Comment: But in postman response I added. return response()->json(['CardSave' => $html, 'message' => 'Success'], 201);

Comment: and where will be store test.html

Comment: Please help for that, I am tired from 2 days with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$data = 'variables data';
$html = view('template1',compact('data'));
$html = $html->render();
File::put('test.html',$html);
```